# Tensorflow error with input to dynamic_rnn ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1, ?)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a newer to tensorflow and Python. I would like to use dynamic RNN to construct sentence embeddings. I want to use variable-length sequences. I would have for each sentence its embedding. I really need your help.

Here is a part of my code:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size,None])
embedding_mat = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size,embedding_size], 0.0, 1.0),dtype=tf.float32)
embedding_output = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_mat,x_data)
with tf.variable_scope('cell_def'):
    cell=tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(num_units = rnn_size,reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
    hidden_state_in =cell.zero_state(batch_size,tf.float32) 
with tf.variable_scope('gru_def'):
    output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, embedding_output,initial_state=hidden_state_in,dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      #read_sent_data is a method that has as input my text corpus and return a list of arrays, each array represent the sentence with its words' ids
      input_data=read_sent_data(file1)#file1 is my corpus file
      for input_sent in input_data:
          #input_sent=tf.reshape(1,len(input_sent))
          print(sess.run(output,feed_dict={x_data:input_sent}))
          outputs.append(output)
      tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()    
sess.close()    
print (outputs.eval())
```

When I run my code I have this error:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(1, ?)'

produced by:

```
print(sess.run(output,feed_dict={x_data:input_sent}))
```

I think that I have a problem with my input which is not a tensor. I try to reshape it by: `input_sent=tf.reshape(1,len(input_sent))` but I get this error:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'Reshape' (op:
> 'Reshape') with input shapes: [], [].

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does `read_sent_data` return batches of words?

Comment: No it returns a list of arrays. Each of array represent the words' ids of a phrase.

Comment: If you make it return batches of `batch_size`, it'll work.